# Error ora 06576 , Calling Oracle Stored Procedure C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

hi guys am building c# application generated via ASP.NET Maker
And am trying to call oracle procedure so, I wrote the following:

```
var OraConn = ew_GetConn();
string sql = "CALL CPM.READING_DATA_TEST";
OraConn.ExecuteNonQuery(sql);
```

Where `reading_data_test` is the name of my stored procedure, And `CPM` the name of schema which contain the procedure 
so i got this error

```
ora-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

And am very sure the name of procedure is correct 100 %

Comment: remove **call** from sql statement.

Comment: already tried and got  ORA-00900 error

Comment: have you tried with CommandType.StoredProcedure

Comment: already tried not working because my application generated by  ASP.NET Maker

Comment: provide full code for above problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to add the round brackets:

```
String sql = "CALL CPM.READING_DATA_TEST()";
```

I say this because in SQL*Plus you can replicate your error as follows:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure donull as begin null; end;
  2  /
Procedure created.

SQL> exec donull;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> call donull;
call donull
     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name


SQL> call donull();

Call completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: how i can pass my_number parameter to the procedure ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940587/calling-oracle-stored-procedure-from-c